# Printing out random images form an array

Tags: php, arrays, image

I have created an array which contains 2 images, I want to show these images randomly (so one shows then when the page is refreshed a different show, etc) I have re-used code i used a long time ago and it doesn't seem to be working could someone help me with where i am going wrong please.

```
<?php
$images = array(
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/man_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/woman_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>'
        );

    shuffle($images); // Randomize images array;
    ?>

<?php echo "<img class="succes_img" src='$images[]'";?>
```

I believe it is how i am trying to echo ut the Image but everything i try i keep getting this error message

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/domain/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml on line 42

Line 42 is where the echo is

Thank you in advance

Comment: need to escape the " in the echo statement. \"succes_img\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your array values contain html markup so the value you are echoing  would be all of that html markup inside of the img tag. Second you are using single quotes around your $images array which whould tell php to print out $images[] instead of the value of the array. Third when you are echoing the array you are not giving an index value. The following code should work assuming you are wanting to leave the html markup inside the array:

```
<?php echo $images[0];?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that you can not only make it random, but you can make it dynamic so it automatically adjusts if you choose to add more images to the array.

```
$i = mt_rand(0, count($images));

src=$images[$i]
```

Note that doing it this way you do not need to shuffle the array. Also, you just need the img url's in the array, not the rest of the html.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$images = array(
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/man_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/woman_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>'
        );

    shuffle($images); // Randomize images array;
    ?>

<?php
 echo $images[0];
?>
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$images = array(
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/man_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img class="succes_img" src="/skin/frontend/theme/default/images/woman_feedback.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>'
        );

    ?>

<?php 
echo $images[shuffle($images)];
?>
```

Single quotes force the string to be evaluated as a string and variable values will not be used.  Use single quotes around special characters then you won't have to escape them.